# JSQMessageBubble Doesn't resize properly while using realm datasource

Tags: ios, realm, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Hi I am migrating one of my existing app to use Realm. My app uses JSQMessagesViewController for the chat UI. I made necessary changes in the app so that it supports Realm.

But, currently I am stuck with one problem whenever I use realm object as datasource for the JSQMessagesViewController, the chat bubbles start to behave in a weird way. The bubbles doesn't resize according to the message's text. See the below screenshot.[image: Message Bubble doesn't resize]

I found in one of the issue thread of JSQMessageViewController, instances where others had faced similar issue  - [Cells don't fill whole width](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/636). According to them if I implement **messageHash()** function in my realm model this should fix the issue.

I have implemented **messageHash()** function as it is an required method of JSQMessageData protocol, but I am still facing this issue.

Here's my realm model:

```
class TextMessageItem: Object, JSQMessageData, Mappable {

    // MARK: Persisted properties
    dynamic var messageId = UUID().uuidString
    dynamic var messageText: String?
    dynamic var messageFrom = ""
    dynamic var messageDateTime = Date()
    dynamic var fromName: String?
    dynamic var avatarURL: String?
    dynamic var messageTo = ""
    dynamic var isIncoming = false

    // MARK: init
    convenience required init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    convenience init(messageText: String?, messageFrom: String, messageDateTime: Date? = Date(), fromName: String?, avatarURL: String?, messageTo: String) {
        self.init()
        self.messageText = messageText
        self.messageFrom = messageFrom
        self.messageDateTime = messageDateTime!
        self.fromName = fromName
        self.avatarURL = avatarURL
        self.messageTo = messageTo
    }

    // MARK: JSQMessageData methods
    func text() -> String {
        return messageText!
    }

    func senderId() -> String {
        return messageFrom
    }

    func date() -> Date {
        return messageDateTime
    }

    func senderDisplayName() -> String {
        return fromName!
    }

    func isMediaMessage() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    func messageHash() -> UInt {
        print(self.hash)
        return UInt(self.hash)
    }
}
```

It'd be great if I can get some pointers on how to fix this issue. Thank You.

Comment: What does `self.hash` return? It doesn't appear to be provided by your type. Have you confirmed that it always returns the same value for a given message item?

Comment: @bdash self.hash returns an unique value always of type int. For a given message item the hash will be unique. And yes it returns same value for a given msg item